# Execute macro ms access in office 365

Tags: sharepoint, cloud, office365, ms-access-2013

within ms access office 365, how can I execute a macro.

I don't see a run button in the ribbon tool-bar as I would see normally. So how can i execute the macro and also hints on how to debug the macro if can run

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file with the desktop version of Office then the macros should still work. If you are opening from a browser or web application, then the macros will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

At the point we were developing this, there was no option to write VBA macro code in Access 365. So we used the macro designer surface to create the macro. Once the macro was created, to execute the macro, we created a form and put a button. On the click event of the button we attached this macro to be executed. All these needs to be done through a designer surface. There was no in-line code option

A hint which I learnt, the macro should run under a minute, else the macro will get terminated. So optimize the macro to the best. A technique we used to get around this problem was to split the long running macro into smaller macro's and call each macro one after the other.